# Error Inserting Data From CSV into a SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, python-2.7, csv, insert-into

i am new to python and need help with a error i am not sure how to solve. I am inserting data from csv into a sql server. Following is the code:

```
#Parsing data from csv
pillar_data = csv.reader(file('C:\Projects/Miscellaneous/List_of_titles.csv'))

# Setting up the Connection
con = create_conn(config=config)
start = time.time()
cur = con.cursor()

#Inserting data into sql
for rows in pillar_data:
    format_str="""INSERT INTO top_title_list_india (title, pillar) VALUES ('{Title}', '{Pillar}');"""
    sql_command = format_str.format(Title=rows[0], Pillar=rows[1])
    cur.execute(sql_command)
```

All data points are string. The error i am getting is:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProgrammingError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-163-619604c90732> in <module>()
      2     format_str="""INSERT INTO top_title_list_india (title, pillar) VALUES ('"{Title}"', '{Pillar}');"""
      3     sql_command = format_str.format(Title=rows[0], Pillar=rows[1])
----> 4     cur.execute(sql_command)

ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "s"
LINE 1: ...t_india (title, pillar) VALUES ('"Gortimer Gibbon's Life on ...
                                                             ^
```

I do not know how to correct this. If there is a better method of inserting data from csv to sql server let me know. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
pillar_data = csv.reader(file('C:\Projects/Miscellaneous/List_of_titles.csv'))
```

must be changed to

```
pillar_data = csv.reader(file('C:\Projects\Miscellaneous\List_of_titles.csv'))
```

you can also use

```
pillar_data = csv.reader(file(r'C:\\Projects\\Miscellaneous\\List_of_titles.csv'))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but i am still getting the same error